# Set the width of a fcolorbox

Tags: color, boxes

Hi a very basic question I'm sure, but is there a way to tell `\fcolorbox` in `xcolor` to draw the box of a certain width.

For example with `\fbox` I would do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\framebox[1in]{text}

\fcolorbox{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `makebox` or `parbox` inside `fcolorbox`.

Comment: `\fbox[1in]{text}` would be incorrect; do you mean `\framebox`?

Comment: Your example with `\fbox` doesn't work. You mean `\framebox`.

Comment: sorry both @egreg and UlrikeFischer, quite right. editing it now.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe some packages can help you.

Comment: Hi @MarcoDaniel thanks for your answer. I'm trying to produce a box of a specific height and width for subtitle sections of a table of descriptive information. Each is 2.5 in wide and 0.75cm high, and there are five of them in a four column by 32 row table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `\framecolorbox` macro, but you can easily build one with `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\framecolorbox}{oommm}
 {% #1 = width (optional)
  % #2 = inner alignment (optional)
  % #3 = frame color
  % #4 = background color
  % #5 = text
  \IfValueTF{#1}
   {\IfValueTF{#2}
    {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{\makebox[#1][#2]{#5}}}
    {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{\makebox[#1]{#5}}}%
   }
   {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
 }
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\framecolorbox}{oommm}
 {% #1 = width (optional)
  % #2 = inner alignment (optional)
  % #3 = frame color
  % #4 = background color
  % #5 = text
  \IfValueTF{#1}
   {%
    \IfValueTF{#2}
     {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{\makebox[#1][#2]{#5}}}
     {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{\makebox[#1]{#5}}}%
   }
   {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
 }

\begin{document}
\framecolorbox{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\framecolorbox[4cm]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\framecolorbox[4cm][l]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\framecolorbox[4cm][r]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\framecolorbox[4cm][s]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have the package `xparse` loaded twice. Why does it issue an `Overfull \hbox` when I use a width of say `\textwidth`?

Comment: @azetina Thanks for noting the double loading (innocuous, but bad practice). The `\framecolorbox` macro produces a box with some padding, as usual for `\framebox`, so you have to take into account `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.