# Extra space in command created

Tags: spacing, macros

Consider the following answer given by @egreg which can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111043/10898

Why is an extra 6.799999pt space created when you issue a command like

```
\framecolorbox[\textwidth]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}
```

Does it have to do with the frame separation? A simple way out is to issue a command like

```
\framecolorbox[\dimexpr\textwidth-6.799999pt\relax]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}
```

but this seems too trivial as an answer.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't \textwidth the width of the text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64046/why-isnt-textwidth-the-width-of-the-text)

Comment: *Why 6.8pt?* Because the default width of the line of a framebox -- like that of so many other lines in TeX and LaTeX -- is `0.4pt` and because the default value of thee separation between the edge of the framebox and the edge of the text (the parameteter `\fboxsep`) is `3pt`. Thus, `0.4pt+3pt+3pt+0.4pt = 6.8pt`.

Comment: Addendum: I should have noted in the earlier comment that the default values of `\fboxrule` and `\fboxsep` apply for the "standard" LaTeX document classes, *viz.*, `article`, `report`, and `book`. Some other document classes, no doubt, choose values other than `0.4pt` and `3.0pt`, respectively. Incidentally, the value of `\fboxrule` is usually the same as that of `arrayrulewidth` -- the width of vertical and horizontal lines that occur in `array` and `tabular` environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a different command, say `\framecolorbox*`, when the padding and the rule thickess shouldn't be taken into account.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\framecolorbox}{soommm}
 {% #1 = star
  % #2 = width (optional)
  % #3 = inner alignment (optional)
  % #4 = frame color
  % #5 = background color
  % #6 = text
  \IfValueTF{#2}
   {
    \IfValueTF{#3}
     {
      \fcolorbox{#4}{#5}{
        \makebox[
          \dim_eval:n {#2 \IfBooleanT{#1}{- 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}}
        ][#3]{#6}
      }
     }
     {
      \fcolorbox{#4}{#5}{\makebox[
        \dim_eval:n { #2 \IfBooleanT{#1}{- 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}}
      ]{#6}
     }
    }
   }
   {\fcolorbox{#4}{#5}{#6}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent X\hrulefill X

\noindent\framecolorbox*[\textwidth]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\noindent\framecolorbox*[\textwidth][l]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\noindent\framecolorbox[\textwidth][s]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Slightly modified example, had an overfull box of only 0.8 pt (credit to [Why isn't \textwidth the width of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64046/why-isnt-textwidth-the-width-of-the-text)), now has no overfull box at all (credit to Mico in comments below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}
\usepackage{calc}
\NewDocumentCommand{\framecolorbox}{oommm}
 {% #1 = width (optional)
  % #2 = inner alignment (optional)
  % #3 = frame color
  % #4 = background color
  % #5 = text
  \IfValueTF{#1}%
   {%
    \IfValueTF{#2}%
     {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{\makebox[#1 - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule][#2]{#5}}}%
     {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{\makebox[#1 - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule]{#5}}}%
   }%
   {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
 }%

\begin{document}

\noindent\framecolorbox[\textwidth]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `0.8pt = 2*0.4pt`, where `0.4pt` is the default value of the width of the line that surrounds the box.

Comment: This will behave differently than `\framebox`, where the specified width doesn't take into account the padding (`\fboxsep`) and the rules (`\fboxrule`), but states the natural width of the inner material as for `\makebox`.