# Wanted: Framed box with fixed width and centered content with manual linebreaks

Tags: box, frame

I need a box with the following properties

- framed
- fixed width
- content text is centered
- manual line breaks in the content text are possible

The closest I have is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minibox}
\begin{document}
\minibox[frame,c]{line 1\\longer line 2}
\end{document}
```

But I don't find a way to fix the width of the box.
I want to set it to a fixed value, which is be wider than the automatic width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \fbox{% <- adds the frame
    \parbox{4cm}{% <- fixes the width
      \centering% <- centers the content
      #1%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\foo{line 1\\longer line 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for this very clear answer.

Comment: @azimut You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you this answer:

[Set the width of a fcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111025/set-the-width-of-a-fcolorbox)

The idea is to create a command:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\framecolorbox}{oommm}
 {% #1 = width (optional)
  % #2 = inner alignment (optional)
  % #3 = frame color
  % #4 = background color
  % #5 = text
  \IfValueTF{#1}
   {%
    \IfValueTF{#2}
     {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{\makebox[#1][#2]{#5}}}
     {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{\makebox[#1]{#5}}}%
   }
   {\fcolorbox{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
 }
```

And then you can use it this way:

```
\framecolorbox[4cm]{blue}{blue!40}{what do I do here?}
```

Which would do:

[image]

Of course, if you want it to be a normal box without colors, you can just change the arguments

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But my impression is that I cannot do manual line breaks within the box.